# Usage of "IN" keyword in Spring boot JDBC template

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have this query in spring boot, in one of the dao class.

**QUERY**

```
String sql = select * from language where screen = ? and lang = ? and screenid in (?)
```

**REQUEST OBJECT**

```
{
    "language" : {
         "screen" : "Index",
         "lang": "english",
         "screenid" : ["250","10","44","11"]
    }
}
```

I fetch each of the values, that came from JSON request and store it into bean.

**QUESTION**

The screenid has array of string values, How can I pass that in query ?

I tried,

```
String ids = LangObj.get("screenid").toString();
// this gives the value as ["250","10","44","11"]
```

when passed this value directly to query it forms as `select * from language where screen = 'Index' and lang = 'english' and screenid in (["250","10","44","11"])` and thus not giving any output, I am looking for a query that to be formed like the below,

```
select * from language where screen = 'Index' and lang = 'english' and screenid in ('250','10','44','11')
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation please :

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-in-list

**Example code :**

```
List<Employee> getEmployeesFromIdList(List<Integer> ids) {
    String inSql = String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(ids.size(), "?"));
 
    List<Employee> employees = jdbcTemplate.query(
      String.format("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id IN (%s)", inSql), 
      ids.toArray(), 
      (rs, rowNum) -> new Employee(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), 
        rs.getString("last_name")));

    return employees;
}
```

Comment: The question SQL contains 2 other parameters, so it's not quite that simple.